# linear transformation and standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We have a linear transformation $R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ where in a standard basis there is a matrix:

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

1.)What matrix does belong to this linear transformation in a basis:

$$B = \left\{\quad\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1\\
2
\end{bmatrix} ,\ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0\\
-1
\end{bmatrix} ,\ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\quad \right\}$$

My understanding of this:

1.The standard basis consists of vectors that are independent of each other. How can then a matrix be in standard basis. Does the matrix A consist of these vectors?

2.What does the $R^3\rightarrow R^3$ have to do with this problem , what if the question would be $R^3\rightarrow R^2$ or $R^2\rightarrow R^3$.

3. So a linear transformation is a linear mapping that maps the zero vector to a zero vector. I read all the theory behind it, but still cant figure out the initial problem

Comment: Am I missing something or you are trying to prove that a linear transformation is indeed a linear transformation?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry that was a misunderstanding, I added that myself and now see that its pointless. I will remove this subquestion. But the initial question persists

Comment: Based on these questions I think the best thing that you could do is review the course material leading up to this problem. You’re asking about the very basics of representing linear transformations by matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the matrix representing a linear transformation in a given basis, apply the linear transformation to each basis vector in turn and write the result as a linear combination of the basis vectors.  The coefficients in that linear combination form a column of the matr8ix.

Here, the first basis vector is $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.  A applied to that is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$= 0\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1  \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}- 2\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}+ 3\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

So the first column of the new matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$.